# Add a new column to a Pandas dataframe with a value from a function

Tags: python, pandas

I know this is similar to other questions but I can't find a solution that I can make work.

I have a dataframe that contains grades that looks similar to this:

```
  subj1 subj2 subj3 subj4
0   A     B     A     B
1   B     B     C     B
2   C     C     B     A
```

I want to append a GPA score in a new column so that the result is this:

```
  subj1 subj2 subj3 subj4 GPA
0   A     B     A     B   3.5
1   B     B     C     B   2.8
2   C     D     B     A   2.5
```

the function I use to calculate the GPA is this:

```
def calcgpa():
    for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
        tot = 0
        c = 0
        GPA = 0
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i] == "A":
                tot = tot + 4
                c += 1
            elif row[i] == "B":
                tot = tot + 3
                c += 1
            elif row[i] == "C":
                tot = tot + 2
                c += 1
            elif row[i] == "D":
                tot = tot + 1
                c += 1
            else:
                c += 1
        GPA = tot / c
        return GPA
```

I thought that `df["GPA"] = pd.Series(calcgpa())` would work but it only adds a value to the first row. All others are NaN. Trying to use pd.apply or pd.assign just gave me an AssertionError.

Is the problem with how the function returns the GPA or what is the proper syntax I need to add the new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the output of `calcgpa()`, it is a single float: `3.5` not a list of GPAs, hence why your output only gives 1 value, then Nans.

I would suggest for your code you need to store each GPA value to a list, and assign that as the column instead. This requires some small changes to your code:

replacing `GPA = 0` with `GPA = []` to turn it into a list and moving this to the top of the function, outside of both for loops. Then change `GPA = tot/c`  to `GPA.append(tot / c)` to append each GPA to the list to be assigned as the new GPA column.

Full code:

```
def calcgpa():
    GPA = []
    for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
        tot = 0
        c = 0
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i] == "A":
                tot = tot + 4
                c += 1
            elif row[i] == "B":
                tot = tot + 3
                c += 1
            elif row[i] == "C":
                tot = tot + 2
                c += 1
            elif row[i] == "D":
                tot = tot + 1
                c += 1
            else:
                c += 1
        GPA.append(tot / c)
    return GPA
```

You can then assign this to the GPA column like this:

```
df["GPA"] = calcgpa()
```

Output:

```
  subj1 subj2 subj3 subj4   GPA
0     A     B     A     B  3.50
1     B     B     C     B  2.75
2     C     C     B     A  2.75
```

As posted in the other answer, there are more efficient ways to achieve this, but as your code was close I thought I would amend that to achieve the result

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have A-E, if you have anything else, ensure you replace them wite zero first, you can then do:

df['GPA'] = df.replace({'A':4,'B':3,'C':2, 'D':1, 'E':0}).mean(1)

```
df 
  subj1 subj2 subj3 subj4   GPA
0     A     B     A     B  3.50
1     B     B     C     B  2.75
2     C     C     B     A  2.75
```

Comment: I think he needs `D->1 , E->0` to be added to the mapping

Comment: Sorry, my dataframe is "similar" to the example I gave. A row in the actual dataframe has a column for the student's name, a teacher's comment, and a numerical grade (like 85). Your solution produces this warning "FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction." And an incorrect GPA probably due to the columns containing numerical grades.